# Spring/Hibernate - entities being implicitly persisted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In the following code, CustomerService.test() method persists the customer object implicitly, i.e. without any call to merge() or update(). Why is this the case and how can I force it to persist the entities only when I explicitly call merge/update?

Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/samples")
public class Samples {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(){
        customerService.test();
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private BaseDao baseDao;

    public Customer findById(Long id) {
        return baseDao.find(Customer.class,id);
    }

    public void test() {
        Customer customer = findById(1L);
        customer.setEmail("a@b.com");
    }
}
```

Dao :

```
@Repository("baseDao")
public class BaseDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(BaseEntity entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    public <T> List<T> list(Class<T> entityClass) {
        Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
        List<T> list = session.createCriteria(entityClass).list();
        return list;
    }

    public <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, long primaryKey) {
        return em.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
    }

    public <T> T update(T entity) {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(BaseEntity entity) {
        em.remove(entity);

    }

    public void remove(Class<? extends BaseEntity> entityClass, long primaryKey) {
        BaseEntity entity = em.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
        if (entity != null) {
            em.remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mhlz thanks for understanding :-)

Comment: It doesn't **persist** alright, but if the entity exist, it get managed by the Hibernate, it updates the entity if there were changes.

Comment: @Jens I am not sure you understood the question. The entity is being persisted even without me calling update/merge.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be aware that the method `test` is within a Hibernate transaction. Therefore you need to know your entity life cycle.

[image: Hibernate Life cycle]

After you load your entity, its state is **Persistent**. When you commit the transaction, Hibernate checks all persistent entities within the transaction: if they are **dirty** (have changes), they are updated.

Looking up that diagram, either you can `evict()` your entity or change its email *after* the transaction.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I'm still waiting for my morning coffee!

Comment: Andre, do you mean to say hibernate will implicitly update the entity whenever there are changes? Is there no way to prevent it from doing so? I want to update the entity manually.

Comment: Yes, hibernate will implicitly update the entity whenever there are changes, when the entity is at **persistent** state. If you want to manually update, either find and evict/clear or find and update without a transaction. Closing is not a option because spring already manages the transaction.